# knockoutjs select option not bind

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am very new to knockoutjs. I try to modified a little from [knockoutjs sample] (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) but it didn't work.

```
<select data-bind="option: availCustomers, optionsText: 'CustomerName', 
value: selectedCustomer, optionsCaption: '--- Choose ---'">
</select>
```

and the viewmodel :

```
<script>
function customerViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.availCustomers = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedCustomer = ko.observable();
};

var Customer = function (id, name) {
    this.CustomerId = id;
    this.CustomerName = name;
};

$(document).ready( function() {
    var cvm = new customerViewModel();
    cvm.availCustomers = new ko.observableArray([
        new Customer("12345", "ABC"),
        new Customer("54321", "XYZ")
    ]);
    ko.applyBindings(cvm);
});
</script>
```

so please guide me

Comment: Didn't work isn't enough. Error message and outcome. Ideally a JsFiddle demoing issue

Comment: looks fine like this http://jsfiddle.net/WN2y6/ cheers

Comment: just tried it jsfiddle. result same as in my browser: showing empty dropdownlist

Comment: hi thanks Yusuf Uzun. So just remove document ready?

Comment: thanks again Yusuf Uzun. should be data-bind="options (with s). Uhhh I feel really stupid ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just a mispeling error, the parameter to bind is called "options".

```
<select data-bind="options: availCustomers, optionsText: 'CustomerName', 
value: selectedCustomer, optionsCaption: '--- Choose ---'">
</select>
```